# default scope with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I am using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3.
I am having three models :-
Email
User

I have 2 roles for users => publisher or subscriber

I want to know how can I do it in rails if I want to have Emails for subscribers and from publishers.
Such as, I just write 
Email.find(####).publishers
Email.find(####).subscribers

Without having different table for subs and pubs.
Also, I have an has many through relationship between Email and User.

Also, I want to achieve a default scope that email.publishers.approved? should be visible to users others should be hidden.

Comment: What I get is that you have 3 models Email , User and EmailUser. Email has many Users through EmailUser model. Is it?

Comment: Yes, users are having roles => Publishers || Subscribers

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be to have field 'role' in the EmailUser model.

And then in the Email model add the following two methods:

```
def publishers
  self.users.where(:email_users=>{:role=>'Publishers'})
end

def subscribers
  self.users.where(:email_users=>{:role=>'Subscribers'})
end
```

Comment: This is not default scope solution, how do I restrict Emails from publishers which are not approved ??

Comment: What do you mean DEFAULT scope?? Rails encourages usage of methods. Anyway add another method for filtering approved ones. I thought if I gave this you'll write that. try it.

Comment: I actually want to use DRY so I write the restriction at one place and do not need to write it at any other place, so that it restricts from picking up particular type of emails, if I have a url abc.com.users/emails/112 user can type 113 and can see another email by using methods but if I use default scope, that email will not exist to show

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :email_users
   has_many :users, :through => :email_users

   scope :approved, where(approved: true )
   scope :publishers, joins(:email_users => :user).where(:users => {:role => "publisher"})
   scope :subscribers, joins(:email_users => :user).where(:users => {:role => "subscriber"})


end

class EmailUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :email
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :email_users
   has_many :emails, :through => :email_users

   scope :publisher, where(:role => "publisher" )
   scope :subscriber, where(:role => "subscriber" )
end
```

Then you can simply get approved emails from publishers like this.

```
Email.publishers.approved
```

And to get emails from subscribers.

```
Email.subscribers
```

And to get emails from publishers.

```
Email.publishers
```

Comment: Is it what you needed?